# How can I dectect changes in properties inside my model in viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm bulding my first production App using WPF MVVM, Caliburn Micro and a WCF service.

I have come to a point where I need my ViewModel to track changes in individual properties inside my model. I give you an example. My VM have properties like this:

```
public OrdenesTransporteWCFModel OrdenTransporte { get; set; }
public List<EnumeradorWCFModel> TiposCarga { get; set; }
public List<EnumeradorWCFModel> TiposCamion { get; set; }
public List<EnumeradorWCFModel> MediosContacto { get; set; }
```

OrdenesTransporteWCFModel is a model that comes from a WCF service, and my view could look something like:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TiposCarga}" SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="Descripcion" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=OrdenTransporte.ID_TipoCarga}"></ComboBox>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TiposCamion}" SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="Descripcion" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=OrdenTransporte.ID_TipoMovil}"></ComboBox>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MediosContacto}" SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="Descripcion" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=OrdenTransporte.ID_MedioContacto,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"></ComboBox>

<TextBox IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Path=OrdenTransporte.Numero}"></TextBox>

<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=OrdenTransporte.FechaConfeccion}"></DatePicker>
```

As you can see I'm binding my controls to individual properties inside my model (OrdenTransporte).

Now what I need is my VM to track changes in this properties: for instance I have a bool in my VM property **HasChange** that I need to be activated if any field has changed. Also I have a method **TipoCamionChange** that I need to fire if the ID_TipoCamion Property change.

Is there any way I can achive that?
Thanks!

**EDIT**

As Martin suggest, I implement INotifyPropertyChange on my model and try to subscribe my model to the propertychange event on my model like this:

```
OrdenTransporte = _svc.OrdenesTransporte_GetById(IDOrden);            
OrdenTransporte.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;

private void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "ID_Cliente")
        {
            CargarDirecciones();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I subscribe my vm to model PropertyChange, the data in the model has already changes, so PropertyChanged is never called. If I do:

```
OrdenTransporte.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;
OrdenTransporte = _svc.OrdenesTransporte_GetById(IDOrden);
```

event is not fired anyway because the entire object is replaced with the one returned by WCF service, incluiding INotifyPropertyChange event. Any Ideas?

Comment: see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15822/Bind-Better-with-INotifyPropertyChanged  or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx or just search ´INotifyPropertyChanged´

Comment: Thanks @philsoady for that. I know about INotifyPropertyChange of course. But to do so i need to re-write my model, wich i can't because they come from a WCF service, or completly duplicate my model properties in my viewmodel, wich is completly unpractical. I'm looking a more generic way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: your viewmodel is normally separate to Service model or POCOs. Perhaps your view model can incorporate the service model or underlying POCOs is some way.

Comment: @philsoady: Yes my WCF model (OrdenTransporte) is a separeted class from my viewmodel class. But i don't want to completly re-write my model just to track changes on it.

Answer (score 2):

Do the model classes implement `INotfiyPropertyChanged`?

Then you could set up event handlers in your view model to the changes in the model classes:

```
    modelObject.PropertyChanged += ViewModelOnPropertyChanged;

    private void ViewModelOnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        // react to object change here
    }
```

You could link the events for several model objects all to the same event handler and then set your `HasChange` view model property for example.

If your model objects do not implement `INotfiyPropertyChanged` I do not know a solution.

Comment: Thanks for that, but it doesn't work. please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

You can add IPNC support to your model properties automatically using [Dynamic Castle](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2008/08/04/implement-inotifypropertychanged-with-castledynamicproxy/) (which encapsulates the instances in a proxy) or [Fody](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com.au/2014/06/using-fodypropertychanged-for-automatic.html) (which modifies the IL in a post step at compile time).

UPDATE: If your models are coming from a web service reference then they'll already have IPCN support, you can see this by going to their automatically generated source code in your project. You can also confirm it in code:

```
using (var client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client())
{
    var data = client.GetData();

    data.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        Debug.Assert(false, "PropertyChanged handler invoked.");
    };

    data.SomeMember = false; // <-- will cause the assert to trigger
}
```

Comment: Spelling mistake, sorry. I meant INPC i.e. INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Thanks for that, but it doesn't work. please see my update ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` and INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

private ObservableCollection<EnumeradorWCFModel> _tiposCarga;
public ObservableCollection<EnumeradorWCFModel> TiposCarga
{
    get { return _tiposCarga; }
    set
    {
        if (_tiposCarga != value)
        {
            _tiposCarga = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TiposCarga));
        }
    }
}
```